# Affine Connection

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

On page 74 of Weinberg's General Relativity textbook he writes the following:

Equation 3.2.4:
$$\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda} \equiv \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \xi^\alpha}\frac{\partial^2 \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu}$$
Equation 3.2.7:
$$g_{\mu \nu} \equiv \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} \eta_{\alpha \beta}$$
Equation 3.2.11:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} = \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}\frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\lambda} $$
Equation 3.3.1:
$$\frac{\partial g_{\mu \nu}}{\partial x^{\lambda}} = \Gamma_{\lambda \mu}^{\rho} g_{\rho \nu} + \Gamma_{\lambda \nu}^{\rho} g_{\rho \mu}$$

> "Before solving for $\Lambda$, it is necessary to point out a subtlety in the derivation of Eq. (3.3.1) that has been hidden by our too-compact notation. When we erect a locally inertial coordinate system $\xi^{\alpha} (x)$, we do so at a specific point $X,$ and the coordinates that are locally inertial at $X$ should be so labeled, as $\xi_X^\alpha (x).$ Thus Eqs. (3.2.7) and (3.2.11) should properly be written as
> \begin{equation}\label{1}g_{\mu \nu}(X) = \left(\frac{\partial \xi_X^\alpha (x)}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \xi_X^\beta (x)}{\partial x^\nu} \eta_{\alpha \beta}\right)_{x=X}\end{equation}
> $$\left(\frac{\partial^2 \xi_X^\alpha (x)}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu}\right)_{x=X} = \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}(X)\left(\frac{\partial \xi_X^\alpha (x)}{\partial x^\lambda}\right)_{x=X} $$
> When we differentiate [the first of these two] with respect to $X^\lambda$, we get two kinds of terms. The first kind arises because we set $x=X;$ these contain just the second derivatives ([the second of these two equations]) and can be easily calculated as before. The second kind of term arises because $\xi^\alpha_X (x)$ carries a label X; these terms contain derivatives like
> $$ \left( \frac{\partial^2 \xi^\alpha_X (x)}{\partial X^\lambda \partial x^\mu}\right)_{x=X}
> $$
> and do not seem to have anything to do with the metric or the affine connection."

I am not really sure what "these two terms" are, nor am I sure of "how they arise," and I do not know why the first kind arises *because* we set $x=X$. I understand intuitively that the $\xi$ themselves depend on $X,$ so when we vary $X$ our coordinate system itself is changing. Can anybody please make clear what it is Weinberg is trying to say here?

Comment: I think he means the first type of term is derivatives with respect to the function argument (the x in parenthesis). And the second type of term are derivatives with respect to the label (the subscript X). So, when he has a big X in the denominator of the derivative symbol he doesn't mean the derivative wrt the function argument, he means the derivative wrt the parameter.